# Error Win XP setting serial port state

Tags: java, virtual-serial-port

I have the following code fragment to show a HELLO WORLD by a USB Device (Display Posiflex PD-2800 for POS).

I use the GiovynetDrive library to manage a virtual COM port.

The code runs perfectly (assuming the COM3 is available).

```
    SerialPort = new SerialPort();
    Parameters settings = new Parameters(); 
    settings.setPort("COM3");
    settings.setBaudRate(Baud._19200);
    Port = new Com(settings);   //<<--Seting crash when restart
    Port.sendString("HELLO WORLD");
    Port.close();
```

My problem is that  when I turn off the computer, it doesn't turn off the device (USB power). This cause that the next startup, the code throws the Exception:

```
    java.lang.Exception: Error setting serial port COM3 state.
    at giovynet.nativelink.SerialPort.openPortC(Native Method)
    at giovynet.serial.Com.<init>(Com.java:48)
    .........
```

This forces me to unplug and plug the USB device and then it works well again.

I think this behavior of the S.O. is configurable, but I don't know as.

UPDATE:

When the USB device is in the restart pending state, I can make a print test without problems using a text only printer (generic driver of the S.O.). Then I can see the print test by my viewer but from my java code still not working until I unplug it.

The S.O. is Windows XP and the USB root HUB (of the device management) have unabled the option "Allow the computer turn off the device to save energy".

Comment: Can you still open it up in hyperterm or similar?  My first guess is that you have a buggy peripheral, but it's hard to say.    A quick google search show that the PD-2800 can operate in HID or "Virtual COM" mode, but its not clear how you select that.  Any chance it's coming up in HID mode?

Comment: The driver of the virtual COM is provided by the device. Is the unique way to work of this.

Comment: Using a Portatil with Windows 8, the device restarts without problems when the SO restarts. I can see the initial welcome screen by the viewer.

Comment: Driver bug in XP?  Library bug in XP?